# Cannot toggleClass("hide") the first grid-item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide my grid-items based on their priority value. I use this function when I click a priority option.

'priority' is the grid-item value="" I pass to let the code know which elements to hide with toggleClass... It works with all grid-item after the first one, no matter what priority number I put on the first one I cannot hide It.

```
function orderNotes(priority){
     console.log(priority);
     $('.grid-item+[value='+priority+']').toggleClass("hide");
     $('.grid').masonry(); /* apparently mansory is not the problem */
}
```

Comment: Does your `priority` ever contain a value with spaces?  if so, `$('.grid-item+[value="'+priority+'"]')` <= put quotes around the value

Comment: `+`... are you really sure there's a `+` in say: `.grid-item+`? I think you want `.grid-item[value="'+priority+'"]` - And also, are you sure that your `.grid-item` is an input element that holds a valid `value` attribute? Please share a [mcve]

Comment: Heh, if all it is is the `+` then it's a typo, XD

Comment: It was the `+` ... Thank you.